# Int Factors, step unknown

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

how does the professor go from e^-5t =  -1/6 e ^-6t + c to

x(t) = e^5t - 1/6 e^-t

im confused about this step

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the problem is. How is x(t) defined elsewhere?

Comment: @IsaacBrowne uploaded the whole picture

Comment: I have to say, this is very difficult to read...

Comment: If you're going to upload a picture, at least have the decency of making it readable...

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD uh this isn't my writing? if you read the question before posting you might have realized that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general case: we have the differential equation
$$x'+f(t)x=g(t)$$
$$x'e^{\int f(t)dt}+e^{\int f(t)dt}f(t)x=e^{\int f(t)dt}g(t)$$
The value $e^{\int f(t)dt}$ is known as the integrating factor and is quite useful as now we can apply product rule to get.
$$(x*e^{\int f(t)dt})'=e^{\int f(t)dt}g(t)$$
$$x=\frac{\int e^{\int f(t)dt}g(t)dt}{e^{\int f(t)dt}}$$
Applying this here we have $f(t)=-5$ and $g(t)=e^{-t}$. Thus we have 
$$x=\frac{\int{e^{-5t}*e^{-t}dt}}{e^{-5t}}=ce^{5t}-\frac{e^{-t}}{6}$$
And since we know that $x(0)=\frac{3}{4}$, so we can solve for c.
$$\frac{3}{4}=c-\frac{1}{6} \rightarrow c=\frac{11}{12}$$

Comment: his answer is not in factor form which is why its confusing me

Comment: Oops. I forgot a step, wait one minute.

Comment: There you go. I hope that clears everything up.

Comment: cant you just simply divide out the e^(-5x) on the left side to leave the x alone?

Comment: I'm sorry, where do you see we can do that?